# How to build "su" from sources?

Tags: compiling, su

Try to build custom "su" on Ubuntu 20.04, but start from original sources for test (without changes).
Run

```
apt-get source login
```

I got shadow-4.8.1 dir. Run

```
./configure
make
```

and try run

```
src/su testuser
```

Its does not works! Auth fail error. Run original OS binary:

```
/usr/bin/su testuser
```

and its works fine!
Wtf?

I think some modules/params is missing in build process.

Going to buildlog of shadow package.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/1:4.11.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu1/+build/23780688

and see next ./configure string

```
./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=\${prefix}/include --mandir=\${prefix}/share/man --infodir=\${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-silent-rules --libdir=\${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --runstatedir=/run --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-shared --without-libcrack --mandir=/usr/share/man --with-libpam --enable-shadowgrp --enable-man --disable-account-tools-setuid --with-group-name-max-length=32 --without-acl --without-attr --without-su --without-tcb
```

See there:

```
--without-su
```

Try this ./configure string and its really make all binaries without "su". Try replace it on

```
--with-su
```

And new binary dont work too. Auth fail. :(

Two questions about it.

1. Where can i find buildlog of original "su"?
2. Why fresh builded "su" cant see real OS user, which exists in /etc/shadow|passwd?

Comment: FYI the default implementation of su in Ubuntu 20.04 is provided by the util-linux package

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing is failing in the *compilation* process. But the `su` that you compiled is owned by your user, and does not have the set uid bit set, which means it executes as your user.

Your user does *not* have capability to switch to other user id's. That's reserved for root.

If you run `ls -l /usr/bin/su`, you'll see that it's owned by root and has the suid bit set:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/su
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 55480 Apr  1 21:16 /usr/bin/su
```

You can fix this by running `chown root:root /path/to/your/su` to make it owned by root, and `chmod 4755 /path/to/your/su` to make it setuid.